# When click a button run a form from a different project

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, multiple-projects

```
  private void _btnAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //UserOntrip _pnl = new UserOntrip();
        //_pnl.Show();
        //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.StartupPath.ToString() + @"\_pnlUserOnTrip.exe");

        Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Gina\Desktop\FINAL PROJECT\LogInForm\LogInForm\UserOntrip.cs");

        LoadingScreen _load = new LoadingScreen();
        _load.Show();
    }
    //static void formopen
    //{
    //    ProcessStartInfo  _startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    //    _startInfo.FileName = "UserOntrip.cs";
    //    _startInfo.Arguments = file;
    //    Process.Start(startInfo);
    //}
```

If you know how the driver side and user side of uber works. I want it to apply on my system. Where whenever i click the accept button from driver side project it will open a form from the userside project. What code should I add, in order to achieve such connection from project to project
I hope you can help me this is the last piece for my system to work
and be needing this to pass my re-defence tomorrow
Thank you

Comment: You can't run a .cs file. You might need to check for online tutorials for how to build an Uber like apps. 
A hint: there should be a server that manages the communication between what happens on both applications (Driver, Passenger).

Comment: there is no .exe on a form just project though sir. I also have a server now sir.

Comment: You need to reference the other projects EXE or DLL. Then you can go `OtherProject.UserOntrip form1 = new OtherProject.UserOntrip(); form1.Show();`

Comment: when i done that sir the Userontrip opens in the driver side not in the user side

Answer (score 0):

Tip :

It is easy if you add other project in your current solution then you can open any form or call any method easily.

Comment: so you mean to say sir, that it is the best solution? to have a 2 project one solution. example if form 2 click somethin a form in the form 1 should open

Comment: Correct, You can manage easily and using namespaces you can feel its like a single project.

Comment: im planning to have it like an uber like transaction where the driver accepts and then somethin in the user side will open ...
i have a re defense on my system tomorrow and this is the last thing i need

Comment: Okay, So you have to have use any communication channel between two projects. i.e SignalR,socket or ajax etc..

Comment: i dont have time to build the code for it though :/ tomorrow will be the defense

Comment: Which are the project types ?

Comment: i have build 2 projects the User and Driver

Comment: But in which technology and language ? so I can help you to do something.